# cmake : invoke find_package() after subproject configuration is done

Tags: cmake

I have a repository with subproject that provides export targets.

```
###
### Exports
###
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_PACKAGE_REGISTRY ON)
export(TARGETS mlspp tls_syntax hpke bytes mpark-variant NAMESPACE MLSPP:: FILE MLSPPConfig.cmake)
export(PACKAGE MLSPP)
```

I use `add_directory()` in my main CMakeLists.txt to make subproject build.
But, I can't use `find_package()` for exported targets as `MLSPPConfig.cmake` file is generated after `find_package()`being invoked by cmake-configure.

Is there any way to make configuration of subproject being done before `find_package()` is invoked ?

Comment: If you include subproject via `add_subdirectory`, then its targets are **already available** to you. No needs to `find_package` for obtain them. If you prefer namespace version of a target (e.g. `MLSPP::mlspp` instead of `mlspp`) , you could create an ALIAS for it: `add_library(MLSPP::mlspp ALIAS mlspp)`. Some projects creates aliases for their exported targets by themselves.

Comment: Oh, that helped. Thank you!